# rails: query JSONB column with regular expression

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql-9.1, jsonb

I am trying to match a JSONB object with a regular expression.

I have a rails app (not the same as this one). I have 2 tables House and Pet. A House has many Pet. My Pet table has a JSONB column called pet_description that contains a key value pairs of pet type and gender like so:

```
{ 
  "dog"=>"male", 
  "cat"=>"female", 
  "parrot"=>"male"
}
```

And the migration file for this is:

```
class AddPetDescriptionToPets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pets, :pet_description, :jsonb, default: {}
    add_index  :pets, :pet_description, using: :gin
  end
end
```

In my House model, I have a query that executes a SQL query. It works if I do this query to find all houses that have pets.

```
self.where("EXISTS ( SELECT null FROM pets WHERE pets.house_id = houses.id)")
```

The above works fine.

I am also able to query for a match with a string:

```
self.where("EXISTS (
    SELECT null 
    FROM pets WHERE pets.house_id = houses.id 
    AND pets.pet_description ->> 'cat' ~ 'fem' )")
```

But I want to get the query to work with a regular expression 'fem | emal', and this is not working. Please help, what am I doing wrong here.

```
self.where("EXISTS (
    SELECT null 
    FROM pets WHERE pets.house_id = houses.id 
    AND pets.pet_description ->> 'cat' ~ 'fem | emal' )")
```

thanks,
Greg

Comment: Is it returning results containing `'fem'`? same results as that of working query above that?

Comment: the last query that tries to match 'fem | emal' returns an empty array [].  While the one above it returns the correct set of matching records.

Comment: exactly, so it's just a wild guess but try something like `"'fem' | 'emal'"`, see if it works.

Comment: `self.where("EXISTS (SELECT null FROM pets WHERE pets.house_id = houses.id AND pets.pet_description ->> 'cat' ~ ? )", "'fem'|'emal'")`

Comment: did it work or not?

Comment: I realised I had the spaces in the regular expression that was causing it to fail. It works without the spaces. Thanks for the clues.